# what is different between separated & topology distinguishable?

Tags: general-topology

what is different between "can be separated" & topology distinguishable?

we say that A & B are separated in X if each is disjoint from the other's closure.

we say that A & B are topology distinguishable when there is an open set containing precisely one of the two.

Comment: No, that's the definition of *disjoint*. *Separated* is a stronger property: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separated_sets#Definitions. What you mean by "subscribe" and "distinguish sets", I have no idea...

Comment: thank you . i translate this word from other language and because of that ,this problem happens. but you say right .

Comment: the main idea of my question is differences between disjoint & separated set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and B are disjoint when $A \cap B$ is empty.
A and B are separated when $\overline A \cap B$ and
$A \cap \overline B$ are empty (where $\overline V$ is the closure of $V$, not its complement).